# Why does KDE "forget" my multi-monitor settings?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, kde

I've installed Kubuntu 12.04 (latest patches always applied as they become available) and experience an odd thing. Whenever I customize the multi-monitor settings (i.e. tell it to extend the desktop and which monitor to treat as primary) these settings work for the session, but disappear once I reboot.

Can this have to do with the fact that I encrypt my home directory and such settings are stored in there?

Again, I can apply the settings in the active session, but once I reboot they're "forgotten".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving it as default. You can find that option in the system settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks (Danke), this solved my problem spot on. It's a bit unintuitive, IMO, but thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: I think this is a strange quirk. Maybe if you only use an external projector *once* somewhere, this forgetting is the right thing to do.